# Split nodes in TikZ math nodes matrix with Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, matrices

TikZ matrices and Beamer do not work smooth -- for example, we have to use ampersand replacement work around. Is there a similar work around that allow one to use `\nodepart` ?
The MWE is this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,automata,trees,positioning,shadows,matrix,
arrows,shapes.geometric,shapes.multipart,trees,calc, fit, decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
\begin{tizpicture}
 \node [circle split, draw] {outside matrix \nodepart{lower}works!};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix [matrix of math nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, nodes={circle split,draw}]
 {
 8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
 3 \& 5 \&  7\nodepart{lower}2 \\
 4 \& 9 \& 2 \\
 };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `matrix of nodes` it works. if you use `matrix of math nodes`, you need to stop the math mode `$7$ \nodepart{lower} $2$` and this is not done by that. It just skips the inner two dollar signs that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @percusse Many thanks! I feel very stupid now. I will use just matrix of nodes. Please consider copying and pasting this as an answer. I am changing the title so it may be useful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matrix of math nodes` implements the following node structure

```
\node (<matrixname>-<row #>-<col#>) {$<contents>$};
```

Here `<contents>` is replaced with whatever is found as the matrix entry. When the `\nodepart` is used, it is still in math mode and it trips up the macro. The correct way should have been

```
\node (<matrixname>-<row #>-<col#>) {$<upper contents>$\nodepart{lower}$<lower contents>$};
```

However, surrounding the `\nodepart{lower}` with dollar signs would not work because they are placed in different boxes so unmatched dollar signs trips the macros again. I can't think of any quick fix now.